# Install4j doesn't write into the java preferences store

Tags: install4j

I have two installer `i1.sh` & `i2.sh` and both have respectively `i1.varfil`e & `i2.varfile` where they customize the installation directory.

First, we launch the `i1.sh` as this:

```
[localhost]$ sudo ./i1.sh -q
```

The `i2.sh` is launched by the `i1.sh` via the action Run executable or batch file.

The problem is that in the file `sudo vi /root/.java/.userPrefs/com/install4j/installations/prefs.xml` an entry exists only for the `i1` but never for the `i2`.

[Edit]

After watching this file with the command:

```
watch "sudo cat /root/.java/.userPrefs/com/install4j/installations/prefs.xml"
```

We noticed that the entries for i2 are added and directly overwritten by those of the i1.

Any ideas plz?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run a script after the launching of the second installer to synchronize the `prefs.xml`

> Run script Action:

```
java.util.prefs.Preferences.userRoot().sync();
java.util.prefs.Preferences.systemRoot().sync();
return true;
```

Special thanks to the install4j support team